# Windows Azure storage emulator error Resources

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-storage-emulator

I was using Visual Studio without problems until today, when I ran my web projects with Windows Azure Tools 2.5, I received the following message:

> Windows Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage
>   emulator.     Could not find any resources appropriate for the
>   specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.Resource.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

My version of Windows Azure Tools is 2.5

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with how Visual Studio is trying to access the emulator. Can you try uninstalling Windows Azure Tools and reinstalling it?

Thanks!